# Why does my array store un-needed values

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with my code - I am getting a run-time error. The arrays are only supposed to store 5 values, but it actually stores more.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

const int num = 5;
string t[num], name;
int m[num], score;

for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the name for score # " << i+1 << " :";
    cin >> name;
    t[i] = name;

    for(int j=i; j<= i ;j++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the score for score # " << j+1 << " :";
        cin >> score;
        m[j] = score;
    }
}

for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
    cout << m[i] << endl;

}
```

Comment: What is `for(int j=i; j<= i ;j++)` supposed to do? This will only ever loop with `j=i`, as incrementing `j` obviously puts it past `i`.

Comment: you don't need to use that loop at all.  Just delete the loop and the enclosing brace, make the Js and i.... and you're good to go.

Comment: so where are you getting a runtime error at? and what is the error?

Comment: @y_garcia: Read closer. It has nothing to do with how many values you stored.

Comment: Your inner loop is completely unnecessary.  It will only ever "loop" once.  Your temporary variables are also completely unnecessary.

Comment: How does this even compile? You don't include `<string>`. Other than that the runtime-error cannot be reproduced.

Comment: when I copy your code, I'm getting a compile error with `cin >> name;`

Comment: [compiles fine without the stupid loop](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/990c0127a45b836a)

Comment: @Zeta <iostream> includes <string>

Comment: @SamIam:  if you use an older compiler, the insertion operator is not defined for `std::string`.  It is in the newer compilers that support the new standards.

Comment: @Chemistpp one can sure promptly deduce that, but please keep in mind that this is IB, i.e. not supported by the standard

Comment: @ZacHowland, what new standards do you mean? That operator was defined in C++ 1998, but only if you include the right header.

Comment: @Chemistpp, `<iostream>` does not include `<string>`

Comment: @JonathanWakely:  Oops, you are correct.  For some reason I had it committed to memory that C++99 did not have overloads for `<<` and `>>` for `std::string`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I see the distinction.  I was thinking I've used a lot of strings without using `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not experiencing a runtime error because your array stores more than it should. It might be, that when you input the name, it contains spaces. This would make `cin >> score;` read only the first character, leaving the rest inside the input buffer.

Here's the result I run your code:

```
[wolf@Targaryen]:~$ r
Enter the name for score # 1 :Alex
Enter the score for score # 1 :100
Enter the name for score # 2 :Bob
Enter the score for score # 2 :99
Enter the name for score # 3 :Charlie
Enter the score for score # 3 :98
Enter the name for score # 4 :Douglas
Enter the score for score # 4 :97
Enter the name for score # 5 :Evin
Enter the score for score # 5 :96
100
99
98
97
96
[wolf@Targaryen]:~$
```

However, your code does have an issue. The loop `for ( int j=i; j<= i ;j++ )` only executes once, but that won't cause any error.

You should read your name input using:

```
getline(cin, name);
```

Then you should clear out the input buffer by sinking any trash left in it to an unused variable.

I think you may change your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;


int main()
{   

const int num = 5;
string t[num], name;
int m[num], score;

for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
{   
    cout << "Enter the name for score # " << i+1 << " :";
    getline(cin, name);
    t[i] = name;

    cout << "Enter the score for score # " << i+1 << " :";
    cin >> score;
    m[i] = score;
    getline(cin, name); // This line just clear out the buffer. "name" used as a trash
}   

for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
    cout << t[i] << ": " << m[i] << endl;

}
```

Comment: at least this one attempts to address the runtime error

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int j=i; j<= i ;j++)
```

This code makes zero sense you don't need a loop here. The reason is it will only ever have once case.

`i = j` you're setting `j` to `i` there for `j` can never been less then `i`.

```
for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the name for score # " << i+1 << " :";
    cin >> name;
    t[i] = name;


    cout << "Enter the score for score # " << i+1 << " :";
    cin >> score;
    m[i] = score;

}
```

this is the same thing you wrote essentially.

EDIT UPDATE:

Well to answer what the OP was actually asking.... I suppose.

It's simply because you aren't including `<string>`

here is the entire project with a couple of optimizations and error checks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

const int num = 5;
string t[num], test;
int m[num];
bool integer = false; 

for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the name for score # " << i+1 << " :";
    cin >> t[i];
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    integer = false; 
    while(integer == false){
       cout << "Enter the score for score # " << i+1 << " :";
       cin >> m[i];
       if(!std::cin.fail())
          integer = true;
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

}

for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
    cout << m[i] << endl;

}
```

I felt the need for the name and score variables were pointless you can just directly store them into your array. **Also, I would make sure you do some error checking to see when you are `cin` ints they are actually ints not a string.** Hope this helps.

Comment: Might I ask how this addresses the error the OP says he's having?

Comment: I've actually used that code progenhard (though I thought of that myself) but I'm still getting the same error. Is there a way around it?

Comment: +1. This is exactly the solution here. I'm not sure why people are giving you a hard time here.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing it, but this code doesn't appear to make any functional changes to the OP's code.  But the OP says he's getting an error.  How does this address the OP's error?

Comment: @sehe and how is that the answer? I don't follow.

Comment: @progenhard the OP states he's experiencing a runtime error, how would it solve the problem to include <string>? I take it he's using a compiler which indirectly includes <string> from <iostream>, notably msvc if I'm not mistaken, so I don't think compiling the code is the issue here.

Comment: @progenhard how would that not flag a compile-time error? I believe you have it running and I myself don't see why it wouldn't, but if the OP is realy experiencing runtime issues from that code, then something else is at works here.

Comment: I've done everything possible to avoid any errors that can be produced with my new update.